# Scala app crashed upon startup on Heroku, including basic hello world

Tags: scala, heroku, deployment, akka-http

**tldr: getting the following error on the simplest possible Akka server:**

```
2020-11-23T00:24:52.212270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-11-23T00:24:52.239873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-11-23T00:24:52.339576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Trying to deploy to Heroku, not sure what to do.

I have a Scala app running on Akka HTTP that I want to deploy to Heroku. It didn't work, so I made a super basic example that just has a single endpoint ("/") and returns an HTML string. It has only three dependencies all Akka.

I have the sbt native launcher defined in plugins.sbt and the JavaAppPackaging enabled in build.sbt. It works fine locally (`heroku local web`), but when I push to production I get the following logs:

```
2020-11-22T23:57:21.620869+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user <myuser>
2020-11-22T23:57:22.201143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-22T23:57:25.502636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/hello-world -Dhttp.port=12828`
2020-11-22T23:57:27.881143+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to 
run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2020-11-22T23:57:28.043747+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-11-22T23:57:29.231879+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class 
"org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-11-22T23:57:29.231937+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger 
implementation
2020-11-22T23:57:29.232029+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See 
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-11-22T23:57:30.667572+00:00 app[web.1]: Server online at http://localhost:12828/
2020-11-22T23:57:30.667588+00:00 app[web.1]: Press RETURN to stop...
2020-11-22T23:57:30.957876+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-11-22T23:57:31.007237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The last two lines in the logs indicate my app ran. It appears to then have exited suddenly. My guess is that something hit enter on the bash for some reason because of the exit code, since the web app can be terminated by hitting enter.

I changed that to terminating when getting `q` from StdIn. Then I get an NPE:

```
2020-11-23T00:09:30.925091+00:00 app[web.1]: Server online at http://localhost:30082/
2020-11-23T00:09:30.925170+00:00 app[web.1]: Enter q to stop...
2020-11-23T00:09:30.927455+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
2020-11-23T00:09:30.927696+00:00 app[web.1]: at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:21)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.927827+00:00 app[web.1]: at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:8)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.927915+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.927998+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928055+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928131+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928190+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928254+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928324+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928406+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928509+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928583+00:00 app[web.1]: at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Main$.main(Main.scala:8)
2020-11-23T00:09:30.928701+00:00 app[web.1]: at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

So I changed it so that there is no way to terminate from the shell which is useless for deployment anyway and added a port unbinding hook to the program instead. Now I get the following:

```
2020-11-23T00:23:48.274903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-23T00:23:51.899150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/hello-world -Dhttp.port=53789`
2020-11-23T00:23:54.456208+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2020-11-23T00:23:54.664379+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-11-23T00:23:56.447805+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-11-23T00:23:56.447951+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2020-11-23T00:23:56.448056+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-11-23T00:23:59.188735+00:00 app[web.1]: Server online at http://localhost:53789/
2020-11-23T00:24:52.212270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-11-23T00:24:52.239873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-11-23T00:24:52.339576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-11-23T00:24:52.391175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

At this point I just don't know what to do. It seems that no matter what I try the program just cannot connect to the port. Help?

Comment: What do you mean by production? aws machiens? It seems like in the last experience you changed the port from 12828 into 53789. Did you open the port at the machine?

Comment: Probably you are trying to bind to some port which is not accessible on heroku. Can you share your main app code?

Comment: The app configuration should take care of using the environment variable `PORT` to bind the HTTP service